# Modification of Excision Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In the [Excision Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excision_theorem), there is a condition that the closure of U is contained in the interior of A. Now I wonder if the Excision Theorem is still true when this condition is replaced by the following: U is equal to the interior of A, and the closure of U is equal to A. Or by the weaker condition where both "equal to" are replaced by "contained in".

Comment: Why not consider some examples?  Also, if you don't like the ambiguity of this general statement, take a look at the statement for CW or simplicial complexes.

Comment: I could study a lot, but the decrement in favoritism suggests that that is a very bad idea: I would surely reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  Decrement in favouritism, what is that?

Comment: Someone indicated "No research effort", so the wheel has already been invented.

Answer (score 0):

No answers thus far. Let me try something myself, that is better than nothing.

Take for X the union of the three following sets:

- Euclidean xy-plane without x-axis,
- Graph of y = x sin (1/x) in Euclidean xy-plane,
- Origin of Euclidean xy-plane.

Let U be everything below the x-axis and A be U together with what is left from the x-axis. The graph of x sin (1/x) over any closed interval is in C_1(X,A), but only those over a closed interval without zero are in C_1(X\U,A\U).